# How to get level change date

Tags: soql, reporting, formula-field

I have a field on Account named Level. It contains values viz., Manager, Assistant Manager, etc. I need to retrieve accounts with their level in Jan 2017 and Dec2018. How to get the data. I tried using field history but it is not working as expected.

I have a thought like building a formula field with change of this field in the respective months and pulling into the report. Can anyone please help me with this requirment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87545/discussion-between-sastri-and-rahul-gawale).

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to consider historical records, so better to leverage Analytic Snapshot.

Refer [Report on Historical Data with Reporting Snapshots](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_about_analytic_snap.htm&type=5)

> A reporting snapshot lets you report on historical data. Authorized users can save tabular or summary report results to fields on a custom object, then map those fields to corresponding fields on a target object. They can then schedule when to run the report to load the custom object's fields with the report's data. Reporting snapshots enable you to work with report data similarly to how you work with other records in Salesforce.